# NodeJS files is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I am trying to display on page the image/(images) which I already uploaded,but it says that files is not defined.

```
app.get('/profile',(req,res) =>{
gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    // Check if files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      res.render('profile', {files: false})

    } else 
    {
        files.map(file => {
            if(file.contentType === 'image/jpeg' || file.contentType === 'image/png'){
                file.isImage = true;
            } else {
                file.isImage = false;
            }
        });
        res.render('profile',{files: files})
    }
  });
```

I am using EJS view engine. profile.ejs
My code:

```
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
            <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="custom-file mb-3">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="custom-file-input">
                <label for="file" class="custom-file-label">Upload your image</label>
              </div>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit!" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
            </form>
            <hr>
             <% if(files){ %>
              <% files.forEach(function(file) { %>
                <div class="card card-body mb-3">
                  <% if(file.isImage) { %>
                    <img src="image/<%= file.filename %>" alt="">
                    <% } else { %>
                      <%= file.filename %>
                        <% } %>  
                    </div>
                <% }) %>
                  <% } else { %>
                    <p>No files to show</p>
                    <% } %>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I don't understand why I always get this error that files is not defined.
ReferenceError: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Oauth\views\profile.ejs:111

```
    109|         </form>

    110|         <hr>

    111|          <% if(files){ %>
files is not defined
```

Comment: what happens if you change the above to `app.get('/profile',(req,res) => res.render('profile', {files: false}))`

Comment: note: `files.map(file => {` should be `files.forEach(file => {` because a) you're ignoring the returned value, and b) you're changing the original "file" object, adding `isImage` property to it. Not that this is a problem, but for clearer code, use forEach not map

Comment: Please don't repost questions. Instead fix problems in your existing question. You're getting a lot of the same feedback here as on the original, and as mentioned there the problem is most likely "scoping". Please go back to the original and break this down to a small listing which reproduces the problem instead of just parts of your larger application. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the err argument in the callback to start debugging.

```
app.get('/profile',(req,res) =>{
    gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err); // debug the error
        return res.render('profile', {files: false});
    }

    // Check if files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
        res.render('profile', {files: false})
    } else {
        // map the files and set it to itself
        files = files.map((file) => {
            if(file.contentType == 'image/jpeg' || file.contentType == 'image/png'){
                file.isImage = true;
            } else {
                file.isImage = false;
            }
            return file; // You forgot this.
        });

        res.render('profile',{files: files})
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you,but it doesn't work,unfourtunately...

Comment: can you try to console.log(files) inside the callback?

Comment: hmm...it displays nothing

Comment: considering the code modifies `file` inside `files.map` this would essentially be no different to the OP code (OP could use forEach and still get the same result)

Comment: https://github.com/bradtraversy/mongo_file_uploads/blob/master/app.js here is example which I am trying to use to learn how to upload a file and display it later on my page

Comment: how about you console log the err var? @mex111 updated my answer

Comment: this code also doesn't address the described issue ... `files` is `undefined` in this line: `<% if(files){ %>`

Comment: what's the output of the err inside callback?

Comment: that's not relevant @FewFlyBy - because the rest of the (original) code would always result in `res.render('profile',{files: somethingThatIsNotUndefined})`

Comment: he said the files in the callback displays nothing, so maybe there's a useful message inside the err that I want to know. Nothing useful but I just want to know.. you know :)

Comment: Indeed, but that wouldn't explain why files in `<% if(files){ %>` is undefined